# How to load event or call any function on stripe js initialized

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have a checkout page that primarily contains the new Stripe Payment Element. The Html contain load fast because I used SSR but stripe payment element show the issue and reload page 2 or more time then its work properly and some it show the issue stripe is not define.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hello there is the issue of loading stripe.js So do the following steps

1. Here I create one stripe.js import globally file

```js
export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  inject('stripe', {
    load() {
      if (!app.$stripe) {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/';
        script.async = true;
        script.defer = true;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
        app.$stripe = new Promise((resolve) => {
          script.addEventListener('load', () => {
            resolve(window.Stripe('Here stripe key'));
          });
        });
      }
      return app.$stripe;
    },
  });
};
```

2. Where you write your stripe component code just before include following line

```js
const stripe = await this.$stripe.load();
```